# Origin of Cauchy convergence test

Tags: mathematics, reference-request, calculus, real-analysis

Obviously [Cauchy's convergence test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_convergence_test) is named after [Augustin-Louis Cauchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augustin-Louis_Cauchy). Is he the person who first proved this criterion or is it another [misnamed theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_misnamed_theorems)? If so: In which treatise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see :

- Robert Bradley & CEdward Sandifer (editors), [Cauchy's Cours d’analyse : An Annotated Translation](https://books.google.it/books?id=M0or-HGe7D0C&pg=PA84) (2009), page 85-on.

Cauchy's textbook, was first published in 1821; the above is a translation of the second edition (appeared in 1897 into Cauchy’s *Oeuvres complètes*) of the [Cours d’analyse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cours_d%27Analyse).